# Visual Studio not reading tsconfig correctly?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, tsconfig

So, I have a custom npm package that we're trying to use in my company. This package is completely typescript, so I try to build it. However Typescript ignores node_modules by default so I made my tsconfig like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "listFiles": true
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules/custom_module/**/*.ts",
    "app/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

This builds just fine with gulp-typescript, however the Visual Studio build is not so cooperative and can't even recognise things like angular. And it needs to build in VS for automated release.

I've tried replacing "files with "include" and then it can find angular etc, but still not our custom module. And gulp-typescript also can't find our module then.

Is there anything I might need to add/remove here?

Comment: Your custom node module should already be compiled to js when you include it in your project You should only have to include the .d.ts files in your application and map the module loader to load the proper js at runtime.

Comment: @toskv Oh, so you can't just share typescript files that way? Interesting, I'll let them know they should share it prebuilt and with a definition file!

Comment: it's not that you can't but, you shouldn't have to build their project. You would have to replicate their build setup too, it would be incredibly fragile for you to work that way. :) It's also a different project so you'd probably expect to have a deliverable you can use directly (even without typescript).

Comment: @toskv thanks man we got it working that way, maybe you should set it as an answer so we can save this for posterity!

Comment: I added an answer, I'm glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your node module should come in the form of transpiled Javascript code and definition files that describe it, not as TypeScript code that you have to compile yourself again.

Doing so would create a very brittle build environment since you'd have to replicate their build setup into yours.

You should only have to include the .d.ts files (the ones in the node_modules are automatically included by tsc) and if you use a module loader map the module to the proper Javascript files.